# How do I detect Ctrl + S in a Window in C#? My EventArgs don't have `e.Modifiers`

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

This is my first C# (and first Windows) application. I'd like to respond to a multi-key command, but can't figure out how. Examples on the web use `e.Modifiers`, `e.Control`, and `override bool ProcessCmdKey`, none of which appear options in my IDE. My main class is a `System.Windows.Window`, so is that the problem? I keep reading about `Forms`--am I utilizing this?

Here's my class header info.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;
//using System.Windows.Forms.
using Winforms = System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;


namespace ContractCutter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
...
```

And here's where I try to do things. I also only have the `Key` class, not `Keys`.

```
void CutContractKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
                stuff;
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this:

```
private void CutContractKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Key == Key.S && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
     {
       MessageBox.Show("CTRL + S");
     }
}
```